# Mergesort incorrect output c++

Tags: c++

Input : `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}` 
Output : `{8,7,6,9,10,5,4,3,2,1}`

I'm not sure what the issue is. I think it has something to do with the recursion in mergesort. I'm new to recursion so my understanding is not too good. Any hints?

```
#include <iostream>
void mergeSort(int a[], int w[], int n);
void merge(int a[], int w[], int n);
using namespace std;

void mergeSort(int a[], int t[], int n) {
if (n > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        t[i] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(a, t, n/2);
    for (int i = n/2; i < n; i++) {
        t[i] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(a, t, n/2);
    merge(a, t, n/2);
}
}

void merge(int a[], int t[], int n) {
    int leftIndex = 0, leftEnd = n/2; 
    int rightIndex = n/2, rightEnd = n;
    int targetIndex = 0; 

    while (leftIndex < leftEnd && rightIndex < rightEnd) {
        if (t[leftIndex] < t[rightIndex]) 
            a[targetIndex++] = t[leftIndex++];
        else    
            a[targetIndex++] = t[rightIndex++];
    }

    while (leftIndex < leftEnd) {
        a[targetIndex++] = t[leftIndex++];
    } 
    while (rightIndex < rightEnd) {
        a[targetIndex++] = t[rightIndex++];
    }
}

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int a[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    int w[SIZE];
    mergeSort(a,w,SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: plese add the 2 lines that are missing to make it a [mcve] and what did you observe while stepping trough with your debugger?

Comment: The code does not compile. After adding the missing includes and function declaration for `merge` above `mergeSort`, there's still the issue that `w` is undeclared in `mergeSort`.

Comment: the "2 lines" was a bit of an exaggeration, however after your edit it is quite accurate ;) Please make sure the code you show does indeed reproduce the behaviour you describe. It is hard to help when we look at different code than you do

Comment: my apologies. I hope i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem is pointer confusion. One of the C language quirks that is not immediately obvious is that in

```
void mergeSort(int a[], int t[], int n);
```

both `a` and `t` are not arrays, but pointers. There is a special rule for this in the language standard. What this means is that in all instantiations of `mergeSort` on the call stack, `t` and `a` refer to the same areas of memory, and this means that every time you do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
    t[i] = a[i];
}
```

you're changing the same region of memory. After you've done so and returned to the previous call frame, this region no longer contains the data you expect it to contain.

The way to solve this is to define a temporary local buffer where you need it, which is in `merge`. For example:

```
const int SIZE = 10;

// mergeSort is much simpler now:
void mergeSort(int a[], int n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    // sort the left side, then the right side
    mergeSort(a        ,     n / 2);
    mergeSort(a + n / 2, n - n / 2);

    // then merge them.
    merge(a, n);
  }
}

// Buffer work done in merge:
void merge(int a[], int n) {
  // temporary buffer t, big enough to hold the left side
  int t[SIZE];

  int leftIndex   = 0    , leftEnd  = n / 2;
  int rightIndex  = n / 2, rightEnd = n    ;
  int targetIndex = 0;

  // copy the left side of the target array into the temporary
  // buffer so we can overwrite that left side without worrying
  // about overwriting data we haven't yet merged
  for(int i = leftIndex; i < leftEnd; ++i) {
    t[i] = a[i];
  }

  // then merge the right side and the temporary buffer to
  // the left side. By the time we start overwriting stuff on
  // the right side, the values we're overwriting will have been
  // merged somewhere into the left side, so this is okay.
  while (leftIndex < leftEnd && rightIndex < rightEnd) {
    if (t[leftIndex] < a[rightIndex]) {
      a[targetIndex++] = t[leftIndex++];
    } else {
      a[targetIndex++] = a[rightIndex++];
    }
  }

  // If there's stuff in the temporary buffer left over,
  // copy it to the end of the target array. If stuff on the
  // right is left over, it's already in the right place.
  while (leftIndex < leftEnd) {
    a[targetIndex++] = t[leftIndex++];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks! I think I have a long ways to go before I get this recursion thing. But can you tell me how you can add into the array parameter? That is bizarre to me. I am new to c++

Comment: Very nearly always when arrays are used, they are implicitly converted to a pointer to their first element (this is usually called "decaying"). Many people are surprised to learn that this also happens in expressions such as `a[3]`, which is in fact defined as `*(a + 3)`. From there it is pointer arithmetic: `a + n / 2` is a pointer to the element `n / 2` elements after the first one in the array (i.e., a pointer to the middle of the array).

Comment: This way, you create as many temporary arrays as recursion levels, which is extremely wasteful.

Comment: @Walter `merge` is not called recursively, so those arrays never exist concurrently, and creating a new array on the stack is just increasing the stack pointer, which is done anyway.

Comment: I would be able to see your point if the buffers had to be allocated dynamically, and in that case I'd use a sorter class and have the side `vector` as a member, but I consider that out of scope for this question. Anyay, if I were to make this implementation efficient, I'd have to use an in-place sorting algorithm once the subarrays become reasonably small to avoid the bulk of the multiple function calls per element the naive implementation requires and consider concurrency. I do not feel that this would make the main point any easier to see, especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining the errors, let me first emphasize that a function argument like `int a[]` is nothing more than a pointer passed to the function. It points to a region of memory.

Now, `mergesort` requires some temporary memory and works by

1. copying the data to the temporary memory;
2. sorting each half of the data in temporary memory;
3. merging the two halves, whereby writing into the original array.

In step 2, the original array is not needed and can serve as temporary memory for the recursion.

In view of these facts, your code contains two errors:

1. You don't use the arrays `t[]` and `a[]` appropriately. The idea is that `a[]` is both input and output and `t[]` a temporary array. Internally, data are first copied to the temporary array, each half of which is sorted, before merging them fills the original array `a[]`.
2. You don't sort the second half of the temporary array, but the first half twice.

A correct implementation is, for example,

```
void mergeSort(int*a, int*t, int n) {      
    if (n > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            t[i] = a[i];                // copy to temporary
        mergeSort(t    , a    , n/2);   // sort 1st half of temporary
        mergeSort(t+n/2, a+n/2, n-n/2); // sort 2nd half of temporary
        merge(a, t, n);
    }
}
```

Note that since `t[]` and `a[]` are pointers, the operation `t+n/2` simply obtains the pointer to the second half of the array. The result of your code with this alteration is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

Comment: sorry could you explain why you did t+n/2 and a+n/2? How can you add an integer into an array parameter?

Comment: Also having tried the implementation the output results : `5 4 3 2 1 10 9 8 7 6`

Comment: @bg9848 I get the fully sorted (`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`) with my change.